# Place rectangle and text side by side Android

Tags: java, c#, android, canvas, xamarin

I'm trying to place rectangle and text side by side in android canvas. I was able to draw both of them but they are over-lapping in many areas. The rectangles and text are dynamic. the code I have currently is

```
int left = 50;
int top = 50;
int width = 50;
int height = 50;
for (int row = 0; row < rows; row++) {
    for (int col = 0; col < cols; col++) {
        rectanglePaint.Color = (Color.ParseColor("#CD5C5C"));
        canvas.DrawRect(left, top, left + width, top + height, rectanglePaint);
        left = (left + width + 50);
        rectanglePaint.TextSize = 30;
        canvas.DrawText("Mytext", left, top + height - 10, rectanglePaint);
    }
    top = top + height + 10;
}
```

Can anyone please help me solve this?
Note: i Dont have enough reputation to post pictures.

Edit: (my new code follows):

```
for (int col = 0; col < 1; col++) { // draw 4 columns
    rectanglePaint.Color = (Color.ParseColor("#CD5C5C"));
    canvas.DrawRect(left, top, left + width, top + height, rectanglePaint);
    left = (left + width + 50);
    string text = "Mytext";
    int spacing = 10;


    canvas.DrawText(text, left, top + height - 10, rectanglePaint);
 left += rectanglePaint.MeasureText(text) + spacing;
    //left = (left + width + 10); // set new left co-ordinate + 10 pixel gap
    //rectanglePaint.TextSize = 30;
    //canvas.DrawText("Mytext",left+5,top+height-10,rectanglePaint);
    // Do other things here
    // i.e. change colour
}
```

Comment: where do you want to see the 'MyText'?

Comment: i want to see MyText beside the rectangle(Liks this - [] MyText [] MyText [] MyText). im actually creating a Legend for chart in a different layout. im  unable to get both in same canvas.

Comment: So have you tried adjusting the x and y coordinates of the rectangle and text so that they don't overlap?

Comment: i played with width and height, left i have in the code...not much of help.

Answer (score 0):

I think this should put you on the right path, if you change

```
canvas.DrawText("Mytext",left,top+height-10,rectanglePaint);
```

to

```
int spacing = 10;
String text = "Mytext";
canvas.DrawText(text,left,top+height-10,rectanglePaint);
left += rectanglePaint.measureText(text) + spacing;
```

You might need to change the value of `spacing` to get the spacing you want between the text and the next square.

Comment: the text is not visible at all. i only see rectangles. i played with spacing and other values but nothing works.

Comment: Are you sure you've got the code exactly as in my example? I don't see how this could possibly make the text disappear completely. At a minimum, the first instance of "Mytext" should be in exactly the same place as with your original code. If you comment out the last line in my example, then you should be back in exactly the situation as you were in originally, so if you still get no text, you must have changed something else.

Comment: i edit your comment for better representation of code.

Comment: @user2344145 I've added your latest code block to the question.